# How do I redirect specific URL's in the .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mobile, redirect

I want to redirect specific pages only to the mobile version of my website. I can redirect the homepage with the code below but I can't find a way to redirect specific pages. I want to redirect https://www.richmond-medical.com/sm3 to http://m.richmond-medical.com/sm3 .
My problem is when I type in Richmond-medical.com/sm3 on a mobile it goes to http://richmond-medical.com only.
Here is my code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.Richmond-Medical.com$ [NC]    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sm3$    
RewriteRule ^/?a/(.*)$ http://m.richmond-medical.com/$ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} richmond-medical.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://m.richmond-medical.com [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow community Jonathan.I have provided the working example. If it solves your problem do let the other SO user knows by accepting it through clicking the right button near the answer. In case you are struggling with the solution,leave me a comment.

Comment: Thanks it works great - I tried it just now - I have one more question regarding this code please see below if you can help. Thanks again I really appreciate your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working code for the above requirement is below

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(R|r)ichmond-medical.com$ [NC]    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sm3$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://m.richmond-medical.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have clubbed both the rule in an **[OR] clause** so that root domain redirects to mobile one and sm3 redirects to mobile one.

The .htaccess rule can be tested at [.htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=36818f10-b720-5c33-afc0-d5ecae213726)

In case you have some new pages that needs to be redirected to mobile one you can add it to the `[OR]` clause like if we need sm5 to be redirected we just need to add sm5 in `[OR]` clause. We can also club it in the same rewrite condition using `|` like below.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(R|r)ichmond-medical.com$ [NC]    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/sm3|/|/sm5)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://m.richmond-medical.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Your code works great @AnkitRastogi I could not find an answer to this anywhere. I have one more function I need from the access file. If someone was to type in Richmond-medical.com/sm3 to their mobile it just redirects to the mobile home page. How would I modify this code to catch the redirect?

Comment: updated the answer. Added (R|r) condition. If that works upvote the answer otherwise do comment.

Comment: I don't think its just the capital letter although that does help. If I type in the full path https://www.richmond-medical.com/sm3/ then the redirect works or if I navigate to the page on mobile it also works. However an end user may type in richmond-medical.com/sm3 . The main site is in https and the mobile just http. I have already modified your code to include the http only for the mobile site by changing the rewrite rule to http. btw I have upvoted your answer but I have not got enough influence for it to display in public.